# How to install Android ADB drivers on Windows? (Any Android Phone)

Tags: adb, usb, windows, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

How can I install the **Android ADB** drivers on a **Windows 8.x** **PC**/**Laptop**?
I followed tutorials on the internet but nothing worked for me.

> **PS:** The adb driver should be compatible with any **Android** smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on the internet, and I will explain the best method here in my answer.

1. Download this program: http://www.mediafire.com/download/gy3g3gdc1vzcv6a/adb-setup-1.4.2.exe
2. Open the program.
3. Select `Y` on every option.
4. ADB should now be successfully installed on your Windows 8.x computer.

More information can be found [here](http://dottech.org/21534/how-to-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-your-windows-computer-for-use-with-your-android-phone).

Answer (score 0):

I've personally found the [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)'s process and walkthrough always makes this exceptionally simple. Just install, run, let it do its updates, and then click the *Full Driver Installation Guide - Automatic + Manual* to have it guide you through. The process can often be trickier than merely installing drivers, and this will help you know what you need to remove first, and what odd manual steps may be necessary.